# Attaching WinDbg to w3wp.exe causes IIS not to respond to requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, exception, windbg

I am following the steps in [this article](http://dotnetdebug.net/2007/05/21/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception-in-aspnet/) for attaching WinDbg to IIS to find the root cause of an "External component has thrown an exception" error. I am using WinDbg 10 (from Windows 10 SDK) on a Windows 7 on an ASP.NET MVC .NET 4.6 (Visual Studio 2015) app. When I attach WindDbg to the w3wp.exe process, reload the web page, the browser just spins waiting for a response. As soon as I stop WinDbg, the response is received. Looks like WinDbg is stalling IIS for some reason. I have checked/unchecked the 'invasive' checkbox. I enabled/disabled CLR Exceptions. I am not professient in WinDbg.

Any ideas what might be the issue? Or other quick way to troubleshoot that kind of exception? I usually know the issue is a compile error in a partial view after spending some time but I am interested in learning WinDbg's way of finding it (if it can).

Comment: The initial attach will stop all threads. You have to run "g" to set them free.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching WinDbg will cause all threads to suspend. If that is the case, your command prompt looks like this, waiting for input:

[image: WinDbg stoppped]

At this time, if I understand the purpose of the linked article, you should enter things like

```
.symfix;.reload
.sxe clr
.loadby sos clr;.loadby sos mscorwks
```

To resume the threads and continue execution of the program, enter `g`. After that, the command prompt should change to

[image: WinDbg running]

Now do something in your application and wait for an exception, then issue the commands mentioned in the article

```
!dumpheap -type CompilerError
!dumpobject <0xXXXX>
```

or (I would suggest)

```
!pe
```